# How can I display my user custom data in String format?

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm, bson

I'm new to Swift UI and MongoDB Realms. I'm trying to display a user's email (from their respective custom user data) in a text box but I'm getting a weird result that I don't know how to fix. I've been semi-blindly trying all sorts of things hoping something would work but no luck so far. I'm using Email/Password authorization so I know that the email/password wouldn't be stored in the user custom data (I think) but its just an example for what I'm trying to do.

My current code so far below.

```
struct HomeView: View {
    let user = app.currentUser!
    @State var isLoggingOut = false
    
    var body: some View {
        let userEmail = user.customData["email"] ?? "no email"
        let userPassword = user.customData["password"] ?? "no password"
        let userDisplay = user.customData["display"] ?? "no display"
        let userName = user.customData["fullName"] ?? "no name"
        
        ZStack {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(.yellow)

            VStack {

                Spacer()
                Text("Home")

                HStack {
                    Text("Email").frame(width: 100)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(String(reflecting: userEmail))
                }.padding(.vertical)

                HStack {
                    Text("Password").frame(width: 100)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(String(describing: userPassword))
                }.padding(.vertical)

                HStack {
                    Text("Display").frame(width: 100)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(String(describing: userDisplay))
                }.padding(.vertical)

                HStack {
                    Text("Full name").frame(width: 100)
                    Spacer()
                    Text(String(describing: userName))
                }.padding(.vertical)

                Spacer()
                Button("Log Out") {tryLogOut()}

            }.padding(40)
            
            if isLoggingOut {LoginView()}
        }
    }
    
    func tryLogOut() {
        app.currentUser?.logOut {error in}
        self.isLoggingOut = true
    }
}
```

After logging in with a test user, this is what I'm getting in the right HStack text boxes (for example, the top email text box):

```
Email      Optional(RealmSwift.AnyBSON.string("test123@gmail.com"))
```

Obviously what I'm trying to end up with is:

```
Email      test123@gmail.com
```

What am I doing wrong? Everything else works as intended but this problem is giving me a headache. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Also FYI - Everything I am trying to display in the text boxes is stored in the database as Strings according to Atlas so I don't see the problem. However in my `NewUserRegistrationView`, when I create the new user document, I use the following code, I'm not sure if there is anything conflicting with the `AnyBSON` types before inserting the document.

```
struct NewUserRegistrationView: View {

// Email, password, displayName, and fullName obtained from TextFields in the body ...
// createUserDocument() is called after registering and confirming the user

func createUserDocument() {
        let credentials = Credentials.emailPassword(
            email: self.email,
            password: self.password)
        app.login(credentials: credentials) {result in
            switch result {
            case .failure:
                self.statustext = "Document creation failed, try again"
            case .success(let user):
                let client = user.mongoClient("mongodb-atlas")
                let database = client.database(named: "AppDatabase")
                let collection = database.collection(withName: "userDocuments")

                collection.insertOne([
                    "userID": AnyBSON(user.id),
                    "email": AnyBSON(self.email),
                    "password": AnyBSON(self.password),
                    "display": AnyBSON(self.display),
                    "fullName": AnyBSON(self.fullName)
                ]) { result in
                    switch result {
                    case .failure:
                        self.statustext = "Could not add document"
                    case .success(let newObjectId):
                        self.statustext = "Inserted document with objID: \(newObjectId)"
                        self.isDone = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all conditionally downcast all dictionary values to `AnyBSON` to get the `String` value

```
let userEmail = (user.customData["email"] as? AnyBSON)?.stringValue ?? "no email"
let userPassword = (user.customData["password"] as? AnyBSON)?.stringValue ?? "no password"
let userDisplay = (user.customData["display"] as? AnyBSON)?.stringValue ?? "no display"
let userName = (user.customData["fullName"] as? AnyBSON)?.stringValue ?? "no name"
```

Without the cast you get `Any` which prints the *weird* output using `String(reflecting`

---

Then simply write

```
Text(userEmail)
...
Text(userPassword)
...
Text(userDisplay) 
...
Text(userName)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using `String(...)` change it to 'userEmail.description ?? ""`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to display user data is to have a function in your class/struct that converts user data in whatever form to a string and then displays it. This would allow you to just use one function to convert data

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out but I have absolutely no idea why it works or what is happening. Lucky enough, I got it by brute force trial and error. Other answers didn't work unfortunately, but thanks to those for the suggestions.

I changed:

```
let userEmail = user.customData["email"] ?? "no email"
let userPassword = user.customData["password"] ?? "no password"
let userDisplay = user.customData["display"] ?? "no display"
let userName = user.customData["fullName"] ?? "no name"
```

To this:

```
let userEmail = ((user.customData["email"] ?? "email")?.stringValue)!
let userPassword = ((user.customData["password"] ?? "password")?.stringValue)!
let userDisplay = ((user.customData["display"] ?? "display")?.stringValue)!
let userName = ((user.customData["fullName"] ?? "fullName")?.stringValue)!

Text(userEmail)
Text(userPassword)
Text(userDisplay)
Text(userName)
```

Can anyone breakdown how this works? Like what do the question/exclamation marks do? And what is a simpler way to do this (if any)?

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem of decoding any AnyBSON.  Not, user.customData...which in fact always returns `nil`!

I'm upset that it took so long to basically guess at the solution. And even this solution needs a refactor as I'm force unwrapping which means its a ticking bomb.

So I used the Realm call gist:
`collection.findOneDocument(filter: ["userId": AnyBSON(user.id)])`

Using the result:

```
  case .success(let document): 

   let email = document?["email"] ?? "no email"
   print("Email: \(String(describing: email!.stringValue!))")
```

So this returns the email string by itself.  The fact I had to double-unwrap is insane.

Naturally, you want to guard and or if let as necessary.  The document in this case is a Realm Document which is: Dictionary <String : AnyBSON?>